# Como obtener valor de un input disabled en Angular utilizando formBuilder?

Tags: html5, angular

Tengo un pequeño problema, bueno lo primero es que quiero convertir un input en disabled ya que a ese input le asigno un valor de otra variable  y este no puede ser modificado, para esto lo que hago es en el  formBuilder lo siguiente:

```
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({   
      codigo: [{value: this.code, disabled:true}],
      //codigo: [this.code, Validators.required]               
  });   
 }
```

->La segunda linea me desactiva el input, pero cuando lo quiero imprimir por consola no me aparece, la tercera linea del código que esta comentado no lo pone disabled pero si lo imprime por consola.

Este es el código que utilizo para imprimir los datos del formulario cuando le doy enviar:

```
 const data = this.form.value;                
    console.log(data);
```

->Estoy utilizando Angular 9

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Hola amigo, te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes editar tu pregunta luego para que cumpla con lo que has leído y luego podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, ya edite mi pregunta para que fuera más claro para los demás. Gracias por su observación

Comment: nose entiende muy bien el problema que tienes. Puedes elaborarlo mejor porfa

Comment: He tratado de replicar tu problema pero en mi caso si me imprime el valor correctamente. Por favor, debes agregar más código de tu ejemplo para revisar otras posibles causas de tu problema. El problema puede estar en otra parte y solamente con el código que has compartido no es suficiente. Contempla compartir todo el código, incluyendo el método que tienes para imprimir en consola y también el html del input que usas para ingresar el valor, de esta forma podemos ver todo el escenario. En adición, aclarecer mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: Solo una aclaración, `.value` no te proporciona los valores de un `FormControl` que esté deshabilitado, por lo tanto, para obtener todos los valores, incluyendo aquellos deshabilitados, debes usar el método `.getRawValues()`. [Documentación oficial](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue).

Comment: Hola @RRGT19 me faltaba el método .getRawValue()  para obtener todos los campos del formulario incluyendo los que están en disabled. Muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro que te haya ayudado, de igual manera voy a publicar una solución como respuesta para que futuros usuarios con el mismo problema puedan encontrar la solución rápidamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.value` no te proporciona los valores de un `FormControl` que esté deshabilitado, por lo tanto, para obtener todos los valores, incluyendo aquellos deshabilitados, debes usar el método `.getRawValues()`.

Ejemplo:

```
const data = this.form.getRawValues();                
console.log(data);
```

Puedes ver más en la [documentación oficial](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue).

Comment: Claro era eso lo que faltaba, .getRawValue().  Gracias